# How can I sort a ListView alphabeticly BUT with special characters at the bottom?

Tags: android, listview, sorting, character

I want a Listview in alphabetical order, but with the special characters at the bottom of the list.

So it would look something like this:

1. List item
2. Aaa
3. Bbb
4. Ccc
5. Ddd
6. Etcetera
7. '''''
8. ((((
9. $$$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call adapter's `sort` method to perform sorting in your desired way. For example:

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) { //modify it to suit your needs
        return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use Collator(see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html))